# Android Studio AVD Manager cannot update system images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I open my AVD Manager from Android Studio (version 2.1 Preview 1), I am presented with a banner on my AVD list which reads:

`System image update is available       (link:)"Update System Images"`

When I click on the "Update System Images" link, I am presented with the following mysterious error message:

```
**Packages Unavailable**

 The following packages are not available:
    - Package id system-images;android-MNC;default;x86_64
    - Package id system-images;android-MNC;default;x86
```

I don't know what this means or how to resolve it. Web searches have been fruitless. Any ideas?

Here is what I am seeing:
[image]

In response to Zayin, here is what I see when I look for the MNC system images. There doesn't appear to even be an option for installing them.
[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same error before. Just open the package manager and **delete/uninstall everything for Android M** (API 22 MNC Preview). Marshmallow is already out anyway.

You may have to **restart Android Studio afterward** cause it caches that check.

The M release has been removed from the packages for some reason after the Marshmallow release and I think that error means he can't find the upgrade to those images. When you wipe them out it stop complaining and you do not see them anymore on the list of packages.

In Android Studio:

1. Open **SDK Manager**. To do that, go to `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`
2. Make sure you are in the `SDK Platform` tab
3. Uncheck *Android M (API 22, MNC Preview)*
4. Click "OK"

Comment: Anyone who can not find (API MNC Preview) should delete Android SDK Platform 22 and then emulator works like a charm :)

Comment: My SDK Manager showed Android M (API 22, MNC Preview) as "partially installed".  I unchecked it, and Android Studio removed a bunch of things.  I restarted it, but trying to launch my app still fails with "device might have stale dexed jars".

Answer (score 10):

Try removing the MNC (M Preview) folder from your SDK folder.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-MNC/
```

or by opening the standalone SDK manager and selecting it and pressing `Delete # packages`.

Comment: There is no such directory under my ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images, sorry.

Comment: Actually it was the only solution working for me: of course the actual path depends on your machine (Mac, Unix, Windows) and your Android SDK installation folder.

Comment: After following the solution by Daniele Segato, this was also required for me (deleting the system images).  They should be removed when uninstalling them via the sdk manager, but for some reason were not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing for Android N you may open the SDK Manager and notice that there's no "Documentation for Android SDK" under Android 7.0 (24).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK Manager and make sure you have the MNC system images installed

[image]

Comment: I don't see any option to install any system image under the Android M folder. See the original question for a screen grab from my SDK manager.

Comment: you only have 2mnc options at the bottom of your screengrab - I'm assuming theres nothing more there?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the bad crop.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to get un-wedged from this situation, so I reinstalled Android Studio and the Android SDK. That unblocked me directly and took less time and hassle than I feared.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem trying to go through *Android N: Quick Settings* codelab from Google (last updated on June 16, 2016). Turned out the sample code had something like this in app's *build.gradle* file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.android_quick_settings"
    minSdkVersion 'N'
    targetSdkVersion 'N'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

When I went ahead and changed it to:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.android_quick_settings"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

it started to work.